# useReducer logic responsible for handling dublican in the table

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning to use useReducer. I wrote in react input which, after clicking the button, adds an element to the table and displays on the page, I also want to add a logic that will not allow adding two the same elements with the same content to the table, but unfortunately it does not work, please help. console.log works, but adds an item to the array anyway

```
const tab = []
const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD':
          for (const n of state) {
            if (n.name === action.course.name) {
              console.log('repeated text')
              return
            }
          }
          return [...state, action.course]
      }
    }, tab)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to test this without your specific data, but this should work:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD':
          if(state.find(i => i.name === action.course.name))
            return state
          else
            return [...state, action.course]
      }
    }, tab)
```